# Spring batch: How to read files from mount point created in UNIX server location directly?

Tags: java, unix, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, mount-point

I am having the spring configuration to read the files from ftp location as below.

```
<bean id="fileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource"
        value="ftp://FTPADMINTEST:12456@ftp.mycompany.net/IT/SE/box/dev/downloaded/CHI-20863.csv"/>
```

### -------------

using above configuration i could read files.But recently we created mount point for this location to access directly these files.
Created mount point for this location is **/BOX/DEV.**
Now i am trying to access same using the below configuration using the mount pint path.

```
<bean id="fileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource"
        value="file://BOX/DEV/CHI-20863.csv"/>
```

But could not read files and getting the exception: **Input resource does not exist class path resource [/BOX/DEV/CHI-20863.csv]**

Plese suggest me how to configure to use files using mount point location.

Comment: Path case-sensitive, you sure that you write path in correct case?

Answer (score 0):

Is //BOX/DEV/ local path to which the mount is done? If it is a mount you got to use proper local path. Otherwise you have to use ftp path like you did in first one.